# Users cannot see content that I have posted to sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, master-page, user-accounts

I have set up a series of sharepoint team pages for our companies intranet, i have also set one of the pages as the home page.  All the others are a subsite to this home page.  I have customized the navigation through sharepoint branding and applying my own code to the back end.  I am giving these details just in case they are pertinent to finding out the solution to my problem.

In the sharepoint field under the ribbon where you insert the document library's, web parts etc. I have used the "edit source" feature on the sharepoint ribbon to customize this area of the page.  I have linked it to css so it looks nice as well, the only problem is, no one can see what i've updated. They can see all the other pages i have made (which do not have custom content), but they cannot see the info/images i have updated the home page with.

I have already tried giving users 100% permissions and it will still not show up.

Could this have something to do the custom master page work i have been doing?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

1. Make sure they have access to wherever your CSS is hosted. If you have that in a site assets library, they need Read access to that.
2. Users need access to read the master page.
3. The master page needs to be checked in. If it's a publishing site, any time you edit it, it checks out and only you can see changes.

It's usually #3!